# Create a bold enumerated list with parenthesized lower case letters

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I can create an enumerated list with parenthesized lower case letters by using the `enumitem` package (with the `[shortlabels]` option) in the preamble and then using `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]`. I can also create a bold enumerated list by using the `enumitem` package and then using `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]`.

I guess I should be able to exchange `\arabic*` in the last example to something that gives me paranthesized lower case letters, but I don't know what that command would be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `label=(\textbf{\alph*})` to get lower case letters, and `label=(\textbf{\Alph*})` for upper case letters:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{\alph*})]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{\Alph*})]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any resource where I can look up these different commands?